# how to solve not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header error in GAS

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

I've been stuck in getting data with rest api in GAS and I have already put the Auth token on headers but I got error "〜〜〜〜 not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header". Actually , I've already succeeded　in getting this data in Python but I can not get it  in GAS. I hope anyone gives me advice . Thank you so much.

I confirmed id_token is correct.

So my error is caused in var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(data_endpoint, request1);

```
GAS

function myFunction() {
  var login_endpoint = "API URL FOR TOKEN";
  var params0 = {"adminId": "xxxxxx","password": "xxxxxxxx"};

  var request0 = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(params0),
  };
  
  var response0 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(login_endpoint, request0);
  var data = JSON.parse(response0);
  var id_token = data.Result.id_token;
  // Logger.log(id_token);

  var params1 = {'adminId': 'xxxxx','pgId': 'xxxxxxxxx','extraColumn': []};
  var data_endpoint = "API URL FOR USER DATA";
  var request1 = {
    "method": "get",
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    "payload": JSON.stringify(params1),
    "headers": { 
      "Authorization":'Bearer '+ id_token,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions : true 
  };
  var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(data_endpoint, request1);
  Logger.log(response1);
}
```

```
Python

param0 = {"adminId": "xxxxx","password": "xxxxxxx"}
    url0 = "API URL FOR TOKEN"
    response_post = requests.post(url0, json=param0)
    response_data = response_post.json()
    id_token = response_data["Result"]["id_token"]
    headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization":id_token}

    param1 = {'adminId': 'xxxx','pgId': 'xxxxxxx','extraColumn': []}
    url1 = "API URL FOR USER DATA"
    response_get = requests.get(url1, json=param1, headers=headers)
    response_get.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    with open('./test.csv','w') as f:
        f.write(response_get.text)
```

Comment: At UrlFetchApp, when `payload` is used even when `"method": "get"`, it is requested as POST method. Please be careful this. Although I'm not sure about the specification of the API you want to use, if it is required to be the GET method at `request1`, the values of `params1` should be sent as the query parameter? In order to correctly understand about your situation, from `in getting this data in Python`, can you provide the script of python that you have already confirmed as the worked script?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for comment . I've already added Python code .

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. When I saw your python script, I confirmed that the value of `param1` is sent as `data` with GET method. In order to achieve this with Google Apps Script, `payload` is required to be used. But in this case, the request becomes POST method. From this situation, I thought that in the current stage, your python script cannot be converted to Google Apps Script. But for example, in your python script, when `requests.get` is modified to `requests.post`, the script works? If it works, this can be achieve by Google Apps Script. Can you test it?

Comment: Thank you so much . I tried to execute Python script by exchanging get with post and it didn't work . Does it mean it is impossible to access API  in GAS ??

Comment: Thank you for replying. As another modification, when `param1` is used as the query parameter, what result will you obtain? If these didn't work, I'm worry that this conversion might not be able to be achieve with Google Apps Script. For example, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: So what if you the method to `POST` in the Apps Script code? Moreover, just like Tanaike has mentioned above, which API are you using? @KentoTamura

Comment: It provides .csv data and this api is being developed right now so there is still no document  right  now .

Comment: If I use post in this GAS script , I got same error "not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header:"

Comment: I will ask this api vender for this prom

Comment: @Tanaike  I'd like to vote you so could you write some  as answer ??

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. From your replying, I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your python script which worked fine, I thought that the value of `param1` is sent as "data" with GET method. In order to achieve this with Google Apps Script, `payload` is required to be used in the request body. But in this case, the request is automatically changed to POST method. It seems that this is the current specification of UrlFetchApp. By this specification, I guessed that in the current stage, your python script cannot be directly converted to Google Apps Script.

From your additional tests, at the API you want to use, it was found that POST method cannot be used. So, in the current stage, in order to use the API you want to use, I think that it might be required to sent the value of `param1` as "data" with GET method.

#### Note:

- For achieving your goal, for example, how about requesting it to Google issue tracker as the future request? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

  - When the official document of `params` is seen, it says as follows.
  - > the payload (that is, the POST body) for the request. Certain HTTP methods (for example, GET) do not accept a payload. It can be a string, a byte array, a blob, or a JavaScript object. A JavaScript object is interpreted as a map of form field names to values, where the values can be either strings or blobs.